# Technique to deal with occasionally blocking json api?

Tags: javascript, api, jquery, ajax

I have a web app that occasionally (after some idleness) will block a very simple request for small chunks of data (30~50 kb) up to 20 or so seconds. Assuming I can't refactor or modify the API, is there some pattern in javascript or jquery to accommodate a situation like this?

I'm thinking to set a timeout for 5 seconds or so for the api call and retry the ajax request -- via jquery's $.ajax() with the timeout argument. I imagine this could be the equivalent of the user refreshing a slow-loading page. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Are you using synchronous ajax calls?  Asychronous ajax calls should never block.  It is generally bad form to blindly auto-retry something (without special back-off logic) that is going slowly as this can lead to avalanche failure.  System is slow so responses are slow so all clients start bailing and auto-retrying which makes system even worse and things get worse and worse (thus called an avalanche failure - the worse the system is the worse the clients treat it, the worse the system gets until failure).

Comment: @jfriend00 My fault for mis-stating the problem. Yes, I'm using asynchronous ajax calls to fetch the data. The api is what's blocking: by which I mean occasionally it just takes an absurdly long time to return the data (20 seconds) -- even though the sql query on the back end and the amount of data returned are trivial.

Comment: See the rest of my comment.  Blindly retrying things because they are slow can lead to more trouble.

Comment: Interesting thoughts about the avalanche problem. Maybe there is a way to set up the client to retry fetching the data but then also to give it up after 2 or 3 re-tries -- so as not to become too abusive.

Comment: The best course of action actually depends upon why things get slow sometimes and what is causing that.  Even if you can't fix that, knowing why it does that would give you a better idea on how to adapt.

Comment: @jfriend00 great point. It's still a bit of a mystery, but my guess so far is that it's idleness on part of the api that causes it to slow down. The api serving json is a flask/sqlite app that only reads the database and never writes to it -- it seems to be a common pattern for low-traffic web apps and blogs. Occasionally after some minutes of idleness the api will take a bit longer than usual to serve a data request, possibly because it's re-opening the db file rather than working on an already open file socket of it. I need to dig deeper but wanted to do what I can on the front end for now.

Comment: But, if that's the case, does the 2nd request that is started after the first request fails to finish quickly actually finish before the 1st request does?  If it's just overhead to re-establish connectivity, it seems like the 2nd one can't finish before the first one does.

Answer (score 1):

jQuerys .ajax() mathod is asynchronous by default meaning the user can still use the page. To prevent users from getting confused or impatient, they need to know that the page is loading. jQuery gives us hooks to show a loading message:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'service.php',
    success: function(){
        //display results
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
        // start an unobtrusive progress bar or spinner
    }
    complete: function(){
        // hide the progress bar/spinner
    }
}
```